# Add cookies for Steam OpenID

Tags: php, cookies

I'm using [this](https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication) GitHub Repository to allow users to sign in through Steam.

This repo uses Sessions which lasts only a while, or until the browser is closed, so I need to use cookies in order to keep users logged in for a long period.

After some research, from cookie documentation and questions asked, users, have a username and password and not using a third party to log in.

This is my first time using sessions and cookies, so please bear with me.

This is how the code for log in looks like:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

function logoutbutton() {
    echo "<form action='' method='get'><button name='logout' type='submit'>Logout</button></form>";
}

function loginbutton($buttonstyle = "square") {
    $button['rectangle'] = "01";
    $button['square'] = "02";
    $button = "<a href='?login'><img src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_".$button[$buttonstyle].".png'></a>";
    
    echo $button;
}

if (isset($_GET['login'])){
    require 'openid.php';
    try {
        require 'SteamConfig.php';
        $openid = new LightOpenID($steamauth['domainname']);
        
        if(!$openid->mode) {
            $openid->identity = 'https://steamcommunity.com/openid';
            header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
        } elseif ($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
            echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
        } else {
            if($openid->validate()) { 
                $id = $openid->identity;
                $ptn = "/^https?:\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/openid\/id\/(7[0-9]{15,25}+)$/";
                preg_match($ptn, $id, $matches);
                
                $_SESSION['steamid'] = $matches[1];
                if (!headers_sent()) {
                    header('Location: '.$steamauth['loginpage']);
                    exit;
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        window.location.href="<?=$steamauth['loginpage']?>";
                    </script>
                    <noscript>
                        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<?=$steamauth['loginpage']?>" />
                    </noscript>
                    <?php
                    exit;
                }
            } else {
                echo "User is not logged in.\n";
            }
        }
    } catch(ErrorException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
    require 'SteamConfig.php';
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: '.$steamauth['logoutpage']);
    exit;
}

if (isset($_GET['update']) || !empty($_SESSION['steam_uptodate']) && $_SESSION['steam_uptodate']+(24*60*60) < time()){ 
    unset($_SESSION['steam_uptodate']);
    require 'userInfo.php';
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
}

?>
```

I have tried to replace `$_SESSION['steamid'] = $matches[1];` with `setcookie("CookieTest", $matches[1], time()+3600);` and replaced any `$_SESSION` with `$_COOKIE`, and when I try to log in, the cookie is set in the browser, but it doesn't log me in

My question is, how can I implement cookies with this Steam Authentication so I can keep users logged in for future visits?

Comment: Have you called `session_start()` before any output was sent? It should be among your first lines. Also `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top (disable on your live server). The session rather than a plain cookie is the correct place to do this. Do not store the user's steam id in a cookie then use that to reload their session, because it could enable any user to impersonate any other user on your site.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes, I have called session_start(). I edited my post with the full code. I was storing the user steam id just as a test to see if it works.

Comment: What is your reason for using output buffering with `ob_start()`? If you also have display_errors turned on, the main thing you need to be looking for to make sure sessions are working at all, is to ensure session_start() is not causing any "headers already sent" errors. If it is working, PHP will set a cookie like "phpsessid" and you should be able to test if `$_SESSION['steamid']` is set when you load this script.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski As I mentioned in my post, this is a github repository, I didn't write this code. And there is no problem with sessions, they work as intended and the "phpsessid" is set, all good. I want to implement cookies so I can keep users logged in after they close the browser

Comment: Gotcha - I didn't click through github and wrongly assumed you built this code around an external library. The session cookie's default timeout is 0 (browser close), but you can call [`session_set_cookie_params()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to set a longer timeout like multiple days. To do a separate "remember me" cookie implementation you would also need a database to permanently store a token value of some sort which you generate and associate with the user. The simplest path is just extending the session cookie time

Comment: So like `session_set_cookie_params(172800)` should be a 2 day cookie and persist beyond browser close.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Wow, that was easy. Thanks a lot! Do you know if the session id is secure enough to prevent stealing?

Comment: It can be made secure enough, particularly if you use https and set the secure flag on the session cookie (with the same set params function). I'd recommend you review the PHP Session Security section of [this article](https://www.phparch.com/2018/01/php-sessions-in-depth/) It also helps to call `session_regenerate_id()` on each page load

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I managed to make it work, thank you again. My problem now is that is logging me out after 30-60 minutes. I think it's related to PHP configuration. I have tried to use ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 172800) (as I don't have access to php.ini) but still doesn't work. I will try to use session.save_path in case ini_set doesn't overwrite php.ini

Comment: It worked with session.save-path. You should write your answer so I can mark it as the solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct a true thorough "remember me" feature, you would typically need a database to store a generated user token with an expiration date and any other conditions you might decide you need. The token would then be stored in a cookie with `setcookie()`.

But the easiest path forward is to extend the lifetime of the normal PHP session cookie to a time period beyond its default `0` (until browser closed). You can do this with [`session_set_cookie_params()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php), choosing a long lifetime.

```
// Session cookie lasts 2 days
session_set_cookie_params(172800);
```

When using a session cookie or other cookie to identify a user, it is important to be using HTTPS all the time, and set the cookie's `secure` parameter

```
// Specify path, domain, and secure
session_set_cookie_params(172800, '/', '.example.com', true);
```

Another small mitigation you can take against session fixation is to generate a new session ID on each page load by simply calling `session_regenerate_id()`. If a session ID happens to get intercepted, it won't stay valid for long if the real user is still active.